# How to write special character into a DBF file in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, character-encoding, python-unicode, dbf

I'm trying to write this character `É` into a DBF file but I keep getting `UnicodeEncodeError`.

Here's how I'm doing it:

```
def write_into_file(value):
    verdata_table = dbf.Table('VerData.dbf', 'VERS_BDD C(50);')

    verdata_table.open(mode=dbf.READ_WRITE)
    for record in ({"vers_bdd": value},):  # value contains the special character É
        verdata_table.append(record)
```

All I want is to write this character into the DBF file. I guess this has something to do with the encoding of the string when trying to write it into the file but I'm not really sure.

Here the error:
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xc9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

**EDIT**

1) Here the complete traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/amunoz/Desktop/PyCharm-Projects/ac-conversion/bco1_to_bco2.py", line 15, in <module>
    write_into_file(value)
  File "C:/Users/amunoz/Desktop/PyCharm-Projects/ac-conversion/bco1_to_bco2.py", line 11, in write_into_file
    verdata_table.append(record)
  File "C:\Users\amunoz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\dbf\__init__.py", line 5676, in append
    gather(newrecord, dictdata, drop=drop)
  File "C:\Users\amunoz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\dbf\__init__.py", line 8803, in gather
    record[key] = value
  File "C:\Users\amunoz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\dbf\__init__.py", line 3018, in __setitem__
    self.__setattr__(name, value)
  File "C:\Users\amunoz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\dbf\__init__.py", line 3004, in __setattr__
    self._update_field_value(name, value)
  File "C:\Users\amunoz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\dbf\__init__.py", line 3193, in _update_field_value
    bytes = array('B', update(value, fielddef, self._meta.memo, self._meta.input_decoder, self._meta.encoder))
  File "C:\Users\amunoz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\dbf\__init__.py", line 3947, in update_character
    string = encoder(string.strip())[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xc9' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

2) Here the output of `repr(value)`:
    `'Éri'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best answer depends on whether this table is only for use with Python and the `dbf` package<sup>1</sup>, or if you need to share it with other programs.

@snakecharmerb is correct in that you need to provide the appropriate code page when you create the dbf file, and if it is only for use with Python and the `dbf` package then you can specify `'utf8'` (instead of `0xf0`) -- but to the best of my knowledge that is not an industry standard specification for dbf files<sup>2</sup>.

If you need to share the file with other programs, then you'll need to decide on which of the [many code pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page)<sup>3</sup> is appropriate for your data set<sup>4</sup>.

When creating the file, add the code page:

```
dbf.table(table_name, table_fields, codepage=...)
```

---

<sup>1</sup> Disclosure:  I am the author of the [`dbf package`](https://pypi.org/project/dbf/).

<sup>2</sup> I added `'utf8'` primarily for my own convenience.

<sup>3</sup> See the sections on DOS and Windows Emulation code pages.

<sup>4</sup> Currently supported code pages -- use either the hex code or the first string from the tuple pair:

```
    0x00 : ('ascii', "plain ol' ascii"),
    0x01 : ('cp437', 'U.S. MS-DOS'),
    0x02 : ('cp850', 'International MS-DOS'),
    0x03 : ('cp1252', 'Windows ANSI'),
    0x04 : ('mac_roman', 'Standard Macintosh'),
    0x08 : ('cp865', 'Danish OEM'),
    0x09 : ('cp437', 'Dutch OEM'),
    0x0A : ('cp850', 'Dutch OEM (secondary)'),
    0x0B : ('cp437', 'Finnish OEM'),
    0x0D : ('cp437', 'French OEM'),
    0x0E : ('cp850', 'French OEM (secondary)'),
    0x0F : ('cp437', 'German OEM'),
    0x10 : ('cp850', 'German OEM (secondary)'),
    0x11 : ('cp437', 'Italian OEM'),
    0x12 : ('cp850', 'Italian OEM (secondary)'),
    0x13 : ('cp932', 'Japanese Shift-JIS'),
    0x14 : ('cp850', 'Spanish OEM (secondary)'),
    0x15 : ('cp437', 'Swedish OEM'),
    0x16 : ('cp850', 'Swedish OEM (secondary)'),
    0x17 : ('cp865', 'Norwegian OEM'),
    0x18 : ('cp437', 'Spanish OEM'),
    0x19 : ('cp437', 'English OEM (Britain)'),
    0x1A : ('cp850', 'English OEM (Britain) (secondary)'),
    0x1B : ('cp437', 'English OEM (U.S.)'),
    0x1C : ('cp863', 'French OEM (Canada)'),
    0x1D : ('cp850', 'French OEM (secondary)'),
    0x1F : ('cp852', 'Czech OEM'),
    0x22 : ('cp852', 'Hungarian OEM'),
    0x23 : ('cp852', 'Polish OEM'),
    0x24 : ('cp860', 'Portugese OEM'),
    0x25 : ('cp850', 'Potugese OEM (secondary)'),
    0x26 : ('cp866', 'Russian OEM'),
    0x37 : ('cp850', 'English OEM (U.S.) (secondary)'),
    0x40 : ('cp852', 'Romanian OEM'),
    0x4D : ('cp936', 'Chinese GBK (PRC)'),
    0x4E : ('cp949', 'Korean (ANSI/OEM)'),
    0x4F : ('cp950', 'Chinese Big 5 (Taiwan)'),
    0x50 : ('cp874', 'Thai (ANSI/OEM)'),
    0x57 : ('cp1252', 'ANSI'),
    0x58 : ('cp1252', 'Western European ANSI'),
    0x59 : ('cp1252', 'Spanish ANSI'),
    0x64 : ('cp852', 'Eastern European MS-DOS'),
    0x65 : ('cp866', 'Russian MS-DOS'),
    0x66 : ('cp865', 'Nordic MS-DOS'),
    0x67 : ('cp861', 'Icelandic MS-DOS'),
    0x68 : (None, 'Kamenicky (Czech) MS-DOS'),
    0x69 : (None, 'Mazovia (Polish) MS-DOS'),
    0x6a : ('cp737', 'Greek MS-DOS (437G)'),
    0x6b : ('cp857', 'Turkish MS-DOS'),
    0x78 : ('cp950', 'Traditional Chinese (Hong Kong SAR, Taiwan) Windows'),
    0x79 : ('cp949', 'Korean Windows'),
    0x7a : ('cp936', 'Chinese Simplified (PRC, Singapore) Windows'),
    0x7b : ('cp932', 'Japanese Windows'),
    0x7c : ('cp874', 'Thai Windows'),
    0x7d : ('cp1255', 'Hebrew Windows'),
    0x7e : ('cp1256', 'Arabic Windows'),
    0xc8 : ('cp1250', 'Eastern European Windows'),
    0xc9 : ('cp1251', 'Russian Windows'),
    0xca : ('cp1254', 'Turkish Windows'),
    0xcb : ('cp1253', 'Greek Windows'),
    0x96 : ('mac_cyrillic', 'Russian Macintosh'),
    0x97 : ('mac_latin2', 'Macintosh EE'),
    0x98 : ('mac_greek', 'Greek Macintosh'),
    0xf0 : ('utf8', '8-bit unicode'),
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the source, `Table` objects accept a codepage parameter in their `__init__` method, which will override the default, which appears to be ASCII.  So you probably need to create your table like this:

```
def write_into_file(value):
    verdata_table = dbf.Table('VerData.dbf', 'VERS_BDD C(50);', codepage=0xf0)
```

(`0xf0` is the hex code dbf uses for UTF-8 - see the table in `dbf/__init__.py`)

Answer (score -1):

You need to override the default input encoding which is `ascii`. Set the input encoding as "utf-8" like

```
dbf.input_decoding = "utf-8"
```

After this, you can open and write the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't work for me. I still get the same error.